# Reading of CSV file with dictionary (without use of pandas)

Tags: python

Write a python program to read the data in the csv file and generate a report in text file with the following information: The total Sales, The total profit

```
path = "Superstore.csv"
with open(path,"r",encoding="utf-8") as store_data:
        reader = csv.DictReader(store_data)
        
        for row in reader:
                sales = float(row.get("Sales"))
        total_sales = sum(sales)
        print(total_sales)
```

builtins.TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: You're calling `sum` on `sales`, which is a `float`. The `sum` method expects an iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `sales` (the `float`-object which isn't iterable) with each iteration. I think you want to sum up all values.
You can use a list-comprehension for this:

```py
sales = [float(row.get("Sales")) for row in reader]
total_sales = sum(sales)
print(total_sales)
```

Comment: thanks that worked! Also, I've tried the same approach to retrieve my profit sum but there were negative values within the dataset. Tried using list comprehension but i do not quite get where to put it, back in the same sales block or will I have to start a new block with a define function

Comment: Not sure what your data looks like, but for the the _profit_ sum this would be something like `profit_sum = sum([float(row.get("Profit")) for row in reader])`.

Comment: the data within my profit column has +ve and -ve data which balances out to 0 when i sum it together, how am i able to filter out the positive ones and sum them together?

Comment: You can do `[float(row.get("Profit")) for row in reader if float(row.get("Profit")) > 0]` or collect the absolute values with [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs): `[abs(float(row.get("Profit"))) for row in reader]`